# Trying to "make uninstall" redis-4.0.10 after to had "make install" redis-5.0.5 in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, redis, ubuntu-18.04

I have `Windows 10 (Home)` and I have installed `Ubuntu 18.04`

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

In 2018 I have installed manually `redis-4.0.10`

It *mostly* with:

- make
- sudo make install

I can start the server in peace and stop it.

Now I have updated `redis`, thus I got and installed for `redis-5.0.5`, again *mostly* through

- make
- sudo make install

**Note:** I can start the server in peace and stop it. I have confirmed the new version is used.

Therefore in my custom `redis` directory I have:

```
ls
redis-4.0.10  redis-4.0.10.tar.gz  redis-5.0.5  redis-5.0.5.tar.gz
```

Now I want uninstall `redis-4.0.10`

I have read:

- [If I build a package from source how can I uninstall or remove completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely)

Thus within the `redis-4.0.10` directory if I execute `sudo make uninstall` I got

```
sudo make uninstall
[sudo] password for manueljordan:
cd src && make uninstall
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/manueljordan/redis/redis-4.0.10/src'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'uninstall'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/manueljordan/redis/redis-4.0.10/src'
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'uninstall' failed
make: *** [uninstall] Error 2
```

In Google working with the `*** No rule to make target 'uninstall'.  Stop.` pattern I arrived to:

- [How to remove application installed from source code [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276492/how-to-remove-application-installed-from-source-code)

Thus I executed `make clean`

```
make clean
cd src && make clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/manueljordan/redis/redis-4.0.10/src'
rm -rf redis-server redis-sentinel redis-cli redis-benchmark redis-check-rdb redis-check-aof *.o *.gcda *.gcno *.gcov redis.info lcov-html Makefile.dep dict-benchmark
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/manueljordan/redis/redis-4.0.10/src'
```

Thus again with `sudo make uninstall`

```
sudo make uninstall
[sudo] password for manueljordan:
cd src && make uninstall
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/manueljordan/redis/redis-4.0.10/src'
    CC Makefile.dep
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'uninstall'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/manueljordan/redis/redis-4.0.10/src'
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'uninstall' failed
make: *** [uninstall] Error 2
```

What to do? My goal is uninstall this `redis` version `4.0.10` and delete in peace the `redis-4.0.10` directory